# How to navigate to new page when click on submit button using `meteor js`

Tags: meteor, router

I need when click on submit or login button how to **navigate to new page with same window** using **meteor js**. please help me how to write.
when user submit the form page navigate to **admindetails.html page** .I am using router package and the html page and client code is below. My intention is after user **login** load another template in **same window dynamically** .Please help me.

```
Here is html page 

<template name="body">
  <div class="bgbody">
     <div align="center">
    <form id="login-form" action="/admindetails">
        <table>
        <p class="admin">Admin Login</p>
        <tr>
           <td><p for="username">Admin Name</p></td>
           <td><input type="text"  id="username" name="username"  placeholder="UserName"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
               <td><p for="password">Password</p></td>
           <td><input type="password" id="pwd" name="password"  placeholder="password"></td>
        </tr>
            <td></td><td><input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Log In"></td>
        </table>
    </form>
     </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Here is the Client code

```
if (Meteor.isClient) 
{
 Meteor.Router.add({

    '/admindetails':'admindetails'

    })
  Template.body.events
  ({
    'submit #login-form' : function (e,t)
 {
      /* template data, if any, is available in 'this'*/
      if (typeof console !== 'undefined')

        console.log("You pressed the button");
         e.preventDefault();
  /*retrieve the input field values*/
         var email = t.find('#username').value
         , password = t.find('#pwd').value;
           console.log(email);
   Meteor.loginWithPassword(email, password, function (err)
    {
    if (err) 
    {
      console.log(err);
      alert(err.reason);
      Session.set("loginError", true);
     }
     else
     {
       console.log(" Login Success ");
    Meteor.Router.to("/admindetails");
     }
    });
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use the recommended [Iron Router](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router), you use the `go` method:

```
Router.go('/articles/example');
```

or:

```
Router.go('showArticle', {name: 'example'});
```

If you use the old [Router](https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-router), use:

```
Meteor.Router.to('/articles/example');
```

If you don't use any router, start right now. In the meantime, use the stone-age method:

```
window.location.href = '...';
```

Comment: It is working but view is not modify  i am sending my code also @Hubert OG